# Record Types and Workflow Rules

Tags: workflow, record-type

We just started using record types to divide our divisions in SF. I wanted to know when setting up Workflow rules do I need to now specify which record type to apply this to?

How can I go back retroactively adding record type ids to all existing WFs? Good thing is all WFs in existence for now only belong to one record type ID for each Object.

Comment: If you don't, it will just fire for all record types of that object.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the Record Type Id when changing your workflow rules. All you need to do is add a new Evaluation Criteria and specify what record type it is for, using the developer name of the record type. See below for an example:

[image]